# Chrome App Resize Window Keeping Aspect Ratio

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm building a chrome app and I need to be able to resize the window keeping the aspect ratio. I have tried using

```
chrome.app.window.current().onBoundsChanged.addListener(function() {
     val he = 1280-chrome.app.window.current().innerBounds.width;
     chrome.app.window.current().innerBounds.height=chrome.app.window.current().innerBounds.height-he;
});
```

and calculate the maxWidth-actualWidth so I can take out the extra pixels out of the actualHeight and vice versa but it doesn't work(It freezes the app forcing me to kill the process).

Comment: Does `window.onresize = function(event) { /*code*/ };` not work?

Comment: Define "doesn't work", and give more code for your attempt.

Comment: @evolutionxbox chrome.app.window.current().onBoundsChanged method works equal to window.onresize, the problem is not the function, I need to restrict the aspect ratio of the window and can't find how to do it.

Comment: I don't think you can, can you? Surely that's something that's controlled by the OS not by the browser itself.

Answer (score 0):

This way works for me:

```
chrome.app.window.current().onBoundsChanged.addListener(function() {
    var height = chrome.app.window.current().innerBounds.height;
    chrome.app.window.current().innerBounds.width = height * (16/9);
});
```

Where '(**16**/**9**)' is the aspect ratio;

Comment: That should work fine on height changes, but width changes would behave weirdly ("bounce back").